# ToShortDateString is displaying empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

**tentative_date** has a valid date, but when I try to convert to `shortdate`, an empty string is displayed.

```
@if (Model.bookings.tentative_date.HasValue) {    
    Model.bookings.tentative_date.Value.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't see anything because you are not rendering anything.

Inside an `if` block you are in "code mode" in Razor so nothing gets written to the response unless you prefix with `@`.

So you just need to write:

```
@if (Model.bookings.tentative_date.HasValue)
{
    @Model.bookings.tentative_date.Value.ToShortDateString()
}
```